# Using NextResponse.rewrite in middleware of Nextjs version 14 (using app router)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I want to hide query parameter called `page` and keep all the other query parameters.
My plan was to check if there is query parameter called page in `request.nextUrl` and then delete that `page` and rewrite the url by `NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(updatedUrl.toString()));`

From my understanding, `rewrite` is literally rewriting the url exposed in URL but still can get all the query parameters in my server component with `searchParams`. Please tell me if my understanding is wrong or the code is wrong.

````js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const nextUrl = request.nextUrl;
  if (nextUrl.searchParams.has('page')) {
    console.log('yes, with page parameter');
    const updatedUrl = request.nextUrl.clone();
    console.log(updatedUrl.toString());
    updatedUrl.searchParams.delete('page');
    console.log(updatedUrl.toString());
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(updatedUrl.toString()));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/',
};```
````

Comment: `rewrite` do not update the URL in the browser. It changes the URL for next step of URL resolutions steps of Next.js. This step could be either a page, or an API. You may want to try `redirect` if you want to change the broker URL.